# Android Library Projects: Refactoring and Navigation

Tags: android, jar, refactoring, library-project

Currently (it changed quite a bit over time) Android Library projects become jar files in the referencing project. There are some issues with this approach: namely refactoring and navigation through code.

Is there any way to refactor the library that considers to change the dependent projects (e.g. rename)? Right now renames in the library project won't be propagated to dependent project. For each project I currently have to adjust them manually. (Workaround: remove the library reference from the dependent projects and add the library project as a plain Java Project reference.)

Also, navigating from dependent project to the library brings me to decompiled classes inside the library project jar, but not to the source. Is my Eclipse setup messed or is it just the current Android Library way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a **dirty way** to achieve this. You add the library to your dependent project as usual but also as a project in "Java Build Path" of the Project Properties.

In Order and Export the library must be above the Android Dependencies.

Comment: Works great, no problems so far. Really helps a lot when you have a lot of these library projects =)